# INPUT field - Financials calculations and display of comma for thousand (1,000) and decimal (.00)

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, css, ajax

For a website with financial calculations I try to convert every number included into an HTML input field to the format xxx,xxx,xxx.xx with comma for the thousand separator and point for decimal.
Similar as we know it from Excel.

Now the challenge: the input fields are used for the calculations in the form input fields.

So in paralytically the system would need to convert and revert every input field every time a user
makes a changes in a field. This might cause some performance issues with 50+ fields on a website.

Is there solution to display the comma and point as a string, but keep it internally as a decimal digit without crazy hidden input fields etc?

Data are stored into MySQL database tables.

Technologies used: JS, jQuery, CSS, AJAX, MySQL

Answer (score 1):

http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/

Answer (score 0):

you could use  `jQuery.data()` to store the numeric value on each of the elements, ref http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/